# PHP Sort Date Added Order By Biggest Date till Smallest Date

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have a table t_status

```
form_no | status | date_added
1       | ok     | 2013-06-01 15:03:07
2       | ok     | 2013-05-29 10:13:27
3       | ng     | 2013-05-30 11:09:47
4       | ng     | 2013-06-03 08:13:17
```

type of date_added is : datetime.

Now when I sort using `ORDER BY date_added DESC`, it will be like this :

```
3       | ng     | 2013-05-30 11:09:47
2       | ok     | 2013-05-29 10:13:27
1       | ok     | 2013-06-01 15:03:07
4       | ng     | 2013-06-03 08:13:17
```

My question, how can I sort ordering by date_added so that the output can be like this (from most recent date till oldest date) :

```
4       | ng     | 2013-06-03 08:13:17
1       | ok     | 2013-06-01 15:03:07
3       | ng     | 2013-05-30 11:09:47
2       | ok     | 2013-05-29 10:13:27
```

Comment: What data type is the date_added column?

Comment: the type is: datetime..

Comment: sorry datetime I mean... :)

Comment: Are you actually sure of everything you posted ? This doesn't seem to be the behavior it should have, `ORDER BY data_added DESC` should have an output like your third representation.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac069/1/0 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should definitely work for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM t_status
ORDER BY date_added DESC
```

Considering you have a table similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE `t_status` (
  `form_no` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`form_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5;
```